# Deploying via WebDeploy over command line fails due to invalid operation

Tags: .net, ant, msbuild, teamcity, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm trying to automate the deploy-process with TeamCity and WebDeploy. Click-One-Publish out of the IDE works fine, but called from my ANT-script it fails due to invalid request.

Here my ANT:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1250"?>
   <project default="build" basedir="." name="WebDeploy"> 
      <target name="build" description="Baut und Published die Anwendung!"> 
        <exec failonerror="true" executable="${MSBuild}MSBuild.exe"> 
          <arg line=" /t:Rebuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSvc /p:Configuration=${configuration} /p:username=${user} /p:password=${password} /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=${host} ${sln}"/> 
        </exec> 
      </target> 
    </project>
```

Here the error (as good as I can translated):

```
   error: Web deployment task failed.((30.08.2011 09:45:12) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)       
   error: It was tried to execute an invalid operation for the file '4_0_30319'
```

My first suggestion was that the .NET Framework could be broken and so I reinstalled the framework, but this was unfortunately no solution.

Some details to the server-environment:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008
- IIS7
- .NET Framework v3.5 (default)
- .NET Framework v4.0.30319
- Authentification over ActiveDirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for a while I tried a Windows default procedure and deleted the target webspace completely. After recreating the webspace and reconfigure the settings everything works fine. I hope this little epsiode helps some other. :-)